# Run both Cucumber and JUnit tests fom Maven cli

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

I use JUnit5 and try run both JUnit and Cucumber tests from maven-3.6.3 cli with command

```
mvn clean verify
```

but in console I get output that only one kind of test or only JUnit tests or only Cucumber tests. After some investigation I found that it's relate to this dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

With that dependency there are Cucumber tests runs and without JUnit tests.
Can't find a way to run both kinds of tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surefire can not execute both JUnit and TestNG tests. You could create two executions of Surefire. One for JUnit and one for TestNG. See [SUREFIRE-377](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-377). Alternatively, since you are using JUnit 5, consider using the the [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine). It is Cucumbers integration with JUnit 5.